# Broadcast URI to an activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, uri

I am trying to send a URI from a `broadcastReceiver` to an `Activity` but the intent never arrives at the new activity.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String i = intent.getDataString();
    uri = Uri.parse(i);
    Intent o = new Intent(context,Image.class);
    o.putExtra("ImageUri", uri);
    context.sendBroadcast(o);
```

Comment: You need to handle how to receive the broadcast. You can't just send it without declaring where you receive it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `sendBroadcast()` on `Context` to communicate directly with an activity.

Comment: @user3856158: You could start the activity using `startActivity()` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to reuse the instance if it already exists. Your activity would pick up your extra in either `onCreate()` (via `getIntent()`, if the activity did not already exist) or `onNewIntent()` (as a passed-in parameter, if the activity already exists). There are a variety of other possibilities too, particularly if it is OK that the activity might not exist (e.g., pass the data to the activity if it exists, otherwise show a `Notification`).

Comment: startActivity in the broadcastReceiver? if this is what you mean it gives me an error that it is undefined because i am extending the broadcastReceiver and in order to startActivity you need an actual activity

Comment: @user3856158: `startActivity()` is a method on `Context`. You are passed a `Context` in `onReceive()`.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT this gives me an error and the compiler suggests FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: @user3856158: `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` is a value on the `Intent` class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Comment: if i implement the broadcast receiver inside the activity would that be a better solution in order to pass the intent from the receiver to the activity ?

Comment: @user3856158: Only if the activity is running, and only if you're not concerned about security. `LocalBroadcastManager` would solve the security issue.

Comment: The activity needs to start after the intent is caught.The uri needs to be passed to the activity after it is caught and the application needs to run in the background